# macOS Catalina fastlane nokogiri.bundle can't be opened because its integrity cannot be verified

Tags: fastlane, macos-catalina

On mac OS Catalina, for Fastlane, I am seeing an error whenever I try to run any Fastlane command.

> "nokogiri.bundle" can't be opened because its integrity cannot be
>   verified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I researched and found that the mac os gatekeeper was blocking this as it treats it as an unidentified developer.

A similar issue was reported on Fastlane GitHub issues for ruby.
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15186

To allow execution

Goto System Preferences -> Security & Privacy and agree to run the
app